# parsing a json file using play json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am reading a HDFS sequence file and which is of [Long, String] lets call each record as message. message._2 is a json string and i am trying to parse it using play json library but i get the following error when i do it.

Error:

```
found   : Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
required: String
```

Code:

```
val jsonString = message._2.toString();
val json = Json.parse(jsonString);
code = (json(0) \\ "code"); -- > Error is pointing to \\ on this line
```

Comment: Why are you adding `(0)` ? (P.S.: Do not use `;` as line separator)

Comment: I tried (json \\ "code") also but doesnt seem to work and i removed ; still it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `(json(0) \\ "code")` returns `Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]`, and you're trying to assign this value to the variable `code` of type `String`.

So, you may want to do this:

```
code = (json(0) \\ "code").head.as[String]
```

which will get the first item of a list and convert `JsValue` to `String`.

**Update**

As @cchantep suggested, the use of `head` is not safe, so for better safety you can do it with `headOption`, but the result type will be `Option[String]`:

```
val code: Option[String] =
    (json \\ "code").headOption.map(_.as[String])
```

and even more safe code will look like this:

```
val code: Option[String] =
    (json \\ "code").headOption.flatMap(_.asOpt[String])
```

Comment: `.head` should never be used

Comment: @cchantep I agree, `headOption.map(_.as[String])` would be better here, just updated the answer :-)